# Document database one to many - How to determine whether to reference or embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am relatively new to using mongoose and mongodb and trying to figure out what questions I should be asking myself when determining whether to create a new Schema and reference or embed by adding an array to an existing schema when there is a one to many relationship.

**For example:**

I have a User model. I need to keep track of User checkins (this will be a button the user presses on the UI to checking, it will call a POST route to my node api). I am debating on whether to embed an array of checkins to the User model or create a separate checkin Schema and reference User. I decided to create a checkin Schema that has a User reference by id. The reason for this is so I can query all checkins throughout the entire system easily (this is a requirement). I figured if I went the other direction and added an array of checkins to the User model (Schema), I would never be able to retrieve a master list of all checkins without looping through all of the Users in the system and compiling one. Additionally, now that I created a new Schema (model) I don't think I will be able to access a specific user's checkins from the User model, I would need to do a find on Checkins where userId=userId.

I am new to Mongo and Mongoose, so maybe there is a feature here that I might not be aware of.

The question is:

```
User (Schema)
  checkins: [
    {
         ...
    },
  ],

or

User (Schema)
Checkin (Schema)
     User
```

Comment: what is the type of data you are storing in each checkins object?

Comment: just simple fields user: (Object), checkInDate (Date), checkOutDate (Date)

Comment: Better to reference ObjectIds so that you can [`lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) later

Comment: That’s what I was thinking for this specific case as well. Now if it was something that would only ever be related to the user and I wouldn’t need to access a mass list outside of the user I could probably get away with embedding.